# Error in App Module is causing custom selectors in angular to not work

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I was updating my angular app to Angular 16, and my `@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0"` started throwing error, I started the migration from Angular 13. Everything was smooth till 15 and from Angular 16 I started getting this error

```
1. If 'ngx-datatable-column' is an Angular component and it has 'width' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-datatable-column' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

I've added the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` as well.

Edit:

I found the issue it was because I was updating angular 13 to 16 and one of the package did not have the proper module support it was throwing error. After updating that package it started working.

Now I want to understand why a module which had issue when imported in the app module was causing all angular related selectors , ngIf,  and many more to throw error.